# Deploy Oracle Apex app through different schema of database

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I want to install apex app. I know of two ways to install any app.

1. Importing export file via Apex designer interface from the same workspace
2. Or, copy the app export file let's say f101.sql and execute that as script directly in SQL developer using the database Schema (which is connected to workspace)

I want to do something similar like 2, but instead of using same Schema, I want to use different Schema to execute script but install into the same workspace.

Example: `f101.sql` is app export of workspace `finance_ws`, which is connected to `finance_schema` of database.
I have another schema `deployment_schema`. Could I execute `f101.sql` file in `deployment_schema` so that it gets deployed in `finance_ws` workspace?

Comment: You can assign multiple schemas to the same workspace, either via the UI or with the API call APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_SCHEMA

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve - do you not have access to the finance_scheme ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have access to `finance_schema` but I use only one dedicated schema `deployment_schema` for deploying various objects to all other schemas of database. So I want to use that schema for deploying apex application as well. I'll try with assigning multiple schema to same workspace, that may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deployment_schema` should have APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE assigned. Once assigned, we can deploy/execute any app through `deployment_schema` in any workspace which exist in that database

Answer (score 1):

I'd

- create a new workspace (let's call it `deployment_ws`)
- designate it to `deployment_schema`
- create a developer in that workspace (let's call it `arif`)
- connect to `deployment_ws` as `arif`
- import `f101.sql`

Perhaps you can do it as you wanted, but ... I find the above approach simpler.

---

**[EDIT]**

You'd want to have only one workspace (which is `FINANCE_WS`), but import `F101.SQL` into it so that one application works on `finance_schema`, and another one on `deployment_schema`.

As you can't have two applications with the same ID, you'll have to import `F101.SQL` and **change** application ID during import (that's on the "Install application" tab. Use either "auto assign new application ID" or "change application ID" (manually).

On the same import page, you'll see the **Parsing schema** property - change it to `deployment_schema`. If you don't see it in the list of values, connect as `admin` into `internal` workspace and designate `deployment_schema` to `finance_ws`.

I guess that's what you, actually, wanted ...

Comment: But wouldn't this create the new app in `deployment_ws` workspace? I want to create the app in `finance_ws` workspace

Comment: Aha; it seems I misunderstood the question. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: Thanks but I meant I don't want 2 apps. I want only one app 101 in finance_ws workspace (currently linked to finance_schema). But I want to deploy this app in finance_ws workspace through deployment_schema. This deployment through deployment_schema should not create a new app, but overwrite the existing 101 app in finance_ws

Comment: Aha #2. Try this: **export the application** (so that you'll have backup, if needed). Then go to App Builder and choose that application. Click "Edit Application properties" button (upper right hand side corner of the screen, above "Export/Import" button). To go "Security" tab. Change "Parsing schema" property to "deployment_schema". Run the application.